# Cannot connect with wifi when CLOSE to router

Tags: networking, 16.04, internet, hardware, router

I have an Elitebook 8570w running ubuntu 16.04, and an ac3200 router. Now I have the most peculiar problem with this setup: when I'm close to the router I cannot connect with it but when I go further away I can connect. When it disconnects it asks me to re-authenticate myself(fill in password again).  Experimentation has shown that I cannot connect when I'm within +-6 meters of the router. This also appears to happen when I move the router to another location(so it's not interference). I also switched the router channel around and that didn't resolve the problem either (tried channels 1-4-8-11).

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 04
       serial: a4:5d:36:9b:ab:c3
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.15-4 ip=192.168.0.171 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:31 memory:d9400000-d941ffff memory:d943b000-d943bfff ioport:5040(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Ultimate-N 6300
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:25:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 3e
       serial: 3c:a9:f4:7a:35:f0
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-59-generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:33 memory:d9100000-d9101fff
```

and

```
$ lspci -vnn 
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [103c:176b]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ivb_uncore

00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port [8086:0151] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
    Memory behind bridge: d8000000-d90fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0000000-00000000d1ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [103c:176b]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at d9420000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller [103c:176b]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
    Memory at d9435000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [103c:176b]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Memory at d9400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Memory at d943b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    I/O ports at 5040 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e

00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller [103c:176b]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at d943a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [103c:176b]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34
    Memory at d9430000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: d9300000-d93fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1e12] (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=23, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: d4000000-d7ffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d2000000-00000000d21fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1e14] (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=24, subordinate=24, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: d9200000-d92fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1e16] (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=25, subordinate=25, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: d9100000-d91fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller [103c:176b]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at d9439000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e55] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [103c:176b]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 RAID bus controller [0104]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] [8086:282a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] [103c:176b]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    I/O ports at 5068 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 5074 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 5060 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 5070 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 5020 [size=32]
    Memory at d9438000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [103c:176b]
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
    Memory at d9434000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at ef80 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K1000M] [10de:0ffc] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName: 0
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GK107GLM [Quadro K1000M] [103c:176b]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 35
    Memory at d8000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at d9080000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_367, nvidia_367_drm

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 HDMI Audio Controller [10de:0e1b] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GK107 HDMI Audio Controller [103c:176b]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at d9000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

24:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: JMicron Technology Corp. IEEE 1394 Host Controller [197b:2380] (rev 30) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company IEEE 1394 Host Controller [103c:176b]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at d9200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Memory at d9205000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
    Kernel modules: firewire_ohci

24:00.1 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller [197b:2392] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company SD/MMC Host Controller [103c:176b]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at d9204000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at d9208000 [disabled] [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci

24:00.2 SD Host controller [0805]: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller [197b:2391] (rev 30) (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Standard SD Host Controller [103c:176b]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 18
    Memory at d9203000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci

25:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 [8086:422b] (rev 3e)
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 3x3 AGN [8086:1101]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
    Memory at d9100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

and when I'm having trouble with the connection and do the following:

```
$sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

I get the (looping) result

```
Jan 28 11:55:06 AICORE-reboot dhclient[9232]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlo1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x59a3635c)
Jan 28 11:55:09 AICORE-reboot dhclient[9232]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlo1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0x59a3635c)
Jan 28 11:55:14 AICORE-reboot dhclient[9232]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlo1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x59a3635c)
Jan 28 11:55:26 AICORE-reboot dhclient[9232]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlo1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x59a3635c)
Jan 28 11:55:34 AICORE-reboot dhclient[9232]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlo1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x59a3635c)
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <warn>  [1485600938.3017] dhcp4 (wlo1): request timed out
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3018] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed unknown -> timeout
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3182] dhcp4 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 9232
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3183] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed timeout -> done
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3188] device (wlo1): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3192] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <warn>  [1485600938.3201] device (wlo1): Activation: failed for connection 'GLADOS MAINFRAME'
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3214] device (wlo1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot avahi-daemon[1134]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::99ad:80fc:78c3:6eaf on wlo1.
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot avahi-daemon[1134]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address fe80::99ad:80fc:78c3:6eaf.
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot avahi-daemon[1134]: Interface wlo1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3258] policy: auto-activating connection 'GLADOS MAINFRAME'
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot kernel: [15223.206329] wlo1: deauthenticating from 54:b8:0a:37:35:2e by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3317] device (wlo1): Activation: starting connection 'GLADOS MAINFRAME' (dcb05d08-526f-4777-a602-3eb925aa2152)
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3320] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3322] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3331] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot wpa_supplicant[1384]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=54:b8:0a:37:35:2e reason=3 locally_generated=1
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3356] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) access point 'GLADOS MAINFRAME' has security, but secrets are required.
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3356] device (wlo1): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <warn>  [1485600938.3377] sup-iface[0xc52a10,wlo1]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3378] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3402] device (wlo1): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3407] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3409] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) connection 'GLADOS MAINFRAME' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3409] Config: added 'ssid' value 'GLADOS MAINFRAME'
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3409] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3409] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3409] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3410] Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot wpa_supplicant[1384]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot kernel: [15223.223973] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot kernel: [15223.223978] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot kernel: [15223.223980] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot kernel: [15223.223984] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot kernel: [15223.223987] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot kernel: [15223.223990] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot kernel: [15223.223994] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot kernel: [15223.223998] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot kernel: [15223.224001] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot kernel: [15223.224004] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot kernel: [15223.224007] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
Jan 28 11:55:38 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600938.3454] sup-iface[0xc52a10,wlo1]: config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Jan 28 11:55:41 AICORE-reboot wpa_supplicant[1384]: wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with 54:b8:0a:37:35:2e (SSID='GLADOS MAINFRAME' freq=5500 MHz)
Jan 28 11:55:41 AICORE-reboot kernel: [15226.240577] wlo1: authenticate with 54:b8:0a:37:35:2e
Jan 28 11:55:41 AICORE-reboot kernel: [15226.242927] wlo1: send auth to 54:b8:0a:37:35:2e (try 1/3)
Jan 28 11:55:41 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600941.3763] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Jan 28 11:55:41 AICORE-reboot wpa_supplicant[1384]: wlo1: Trying to associate with 54:b8:0a:37:35:2e (SSID='GLADOS MAINFRAME' freq=5500 MHz)
Jan 28 11:55:41 AICORE-reboot kernel: [15226.327692] wlo1: authenticated
Jan 28 11:55:41 AICORE-reboot kernel: [15226.328244] wlo1: associate with 54:b8:0a:37:35:2e (try 1/3)
Jan 28 11:55:41 AICORE-reboot kernel: [15226.329249] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 54:b8:0a:37:35:2e (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=1)
Jan 28 11:55:41 AICORE-reboot wpa_supplicant[1384]: wlo1: Associated with 54:b8:0a:37:35:2e
Jan 28 11:55:41 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600941.4522] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associated
Jan 28 11:55:41 AICORE-reboot kernel: [15226.332641] wlo1: associated
Jan 28 11:55:41 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600941.4724] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Jan 28 11:55:41 AICORE-reboot wpa_supplicant[1384]: wlo1: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 54:b8:0a:37:35:2e [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
Jan 28 11:55:41 AICORE-reboot wpa_supplicant[1384]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 54:b8:0a:37:35:2e completed [id=0 id_str=]
Jan 28 11:55:41 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600941.5562] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jan 28 11:55:41 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600941.5563] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'GLADOS MAINFRAME'.
Jan 28 11:55:41 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600941.5564] device (wlo1): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Jan 28 11:55:41 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600941.5568] dhcp4 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jan 28 11:55:41 AICORE-reboot NetworkManager[1189]: <info>  [1485600941.5583] dhcp4 (wlo1): dhclient started with pid 9248
Jan 28 11:55:41 AICORE-reboot dhclient[9248]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.108 on wlo1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x44238e25)
Jan 28 11:55:43 AICORE-reboot avahi-daemon[1134]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address fe80::99ad:80fc:78c3:6eaf.
Jan 28 11:55:43 AICORE-reboot avahi-daemon[1134]: New relevant interface wlo1.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jan 28 11:55:43 AICORE-reboot avahi-daemon[1134]: Registering new address record for fe80::99ad:80fc:78c3:6eaf on wlo1.*.
Jan 28 11:55:44 AICORE-reboot dhclient[9248]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.108 on wlo1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x44238e25)
```

Anybody have any idea what might cause my laptop to be unable to connect when close to the router?

Oh and before I forget, the problem doesn't occur in windows (duel boot).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have worked on several cases that use the *iwlwifi* driver where connectivity issues were helped when the SSID was changed to eliminate spaces in the name. I suggest that you change the name of your network from GLADOS MAINFRAME to GladosMainframe or GLADOS_MAINFRAME or some such.

As well, there are a few things that you might try to improve connectivity.

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

If these changes do not help, please try:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=8
```

If it helps, make it permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Comment: Changing the band to 20 ghz resolved the problem but that does not explain why this problem occurred in the first place,  I'm curious why this happened.

Comment: I can't tell you the exact technical reason. My answer is based on my own sometimes painful trial and error with Intel wireless over about ten years. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: http://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: your answer was helpful (I upvoted) but it was not the real reason because I still want to know WHY this behavior happened.

Answer (score 0):

It's been nearly two years, but just in case you are still pulling you hair out, I confirm that I have seen similar poor WiFi performance on Ubuntu 16.04LTS, with a Realtek 8188ee WiFi adapter. After **much** research, including Googling and trials on equipment with different WiFi networks at different sites, I conclude that there is definitely a problem within Ubuntu itself, with poor WiFi performance on wireless N. This issue is not specific to Intel or Realtek, it is an Ubuntu problem. On dual boot systems, on exactly the same hardware on the same WiFi at the exact same location, Windows 10 works fine.

I've done limited testing on Lubuntu 18.04LTS, and it has the same problem.

The problem occurs when ....
    - there are lots of WiFi networks in your vicinity on multiple channels
    - your WiFi connection is N, with Channel Width 40MHz

If you configure the router to use 20MHz Channel Width only, the problem goes away.

I believe the iw command can be used to tell your Ubuntu WiFi card to use "HT20", which means 20MHz Channel Width. But I have not succeeded in getting it to work.

Intel WiFi cards have a convenient parameter to completely disable wireless N (11n_disable), as documented by Chili555. Realtek WiFi cards do not - so we have had to disable 40MHz in the router where possible. Not all routers conform to wireless N standards, and the option to disable 40MHz Channel Width may or may not be available.

Performance on wireless G on the same systems is good.

I am no expert, but my understanding of 20MHz vs 40MHz, is that 20MHz means single band communications, and 40MHz means two band communications. The latter means your WiFi connection is actually using two WiFi bands to achieve the 300Mbps throughput.

Hope this is of some use.