# Slow wifi speed in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

I am getting really slow wifi speed in Ubuntu not sure what is the issue.

I tried every solution available on internet but it doesn't seem to improve.
Also it doesn't detect the network change, if I move from one wifi to another I have to restart network manager and networking services to detect new wifi.

I am thinking to move to Windows 10 if nothing works out.

```
 *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 7265
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 59
   serial: dc:53:60:77:9f:25
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-59-generic firmware=17.352738.0 ip=192.168.0.11 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:53 memory:f7100000-f7101fff
```

Wifi strength of the network.

```
egnyte@DL0019 ~ $%nmcli d wifi                                                                                                                                                                       ──(Tue,Jan31)─┘
*  SSID               MODE   CHAN  RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY         
*  b54308             Infra  11    54 Mbit/s  58      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2
```

I have already tried following solutions 
[Very slow internet connection on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764387/very-slow-internet-connection-on-ubuntu-16-04)
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2246002

```
sudo iw reg get
country PL: DFS-ETSI
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS
    (5490 - 5710 @ 160), (N/A, 27), (0 ms), DFS
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

cat /etc/default/crda
# Set REGDOMAIN to a ISO/IEC 3166-1 alpha2 country code so that iw(8) may set
# the initial regulatory domain setting for IEEE 802.11 devices which operate
# on this system.
#
# Governments assert the right to regulate usage of radio spectrum within
# their respective territories so make sure you select a ISO/IEC 3166-1 alpha2
# country code suitable for your location or you may infringe on local
# legislature. See `/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' for a table of timezone
# descriptions containing ISO/IEC 3166-1 alpha2 country codes.

REGDOMAIN=PL
```

Output of `sudo iwlist scan`

```
wlp3s0    Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
                Channel:11
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"b54308"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                          24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=000000039e775843
                Extra: Last beacon: 220ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 0006623534333038
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                IE: Unknown: 03010B
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                IE: Unknown: 0B050100320000
                IE: Unknown: 2D1ABC191BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D160B081500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                IE: Unknown: 7F080500080000000040
                IE: Unknown: DD090010180201000C0000
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101840003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: 46057208010000
      Cell 02 - Address:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
                Channel:2
                Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
                Quality=18/70  Signal level=-92 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"HUAWEI-B315-A548"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                          24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=00000008041fc18b
                Extra: Last beacon: 632ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 00104855415745492D423331352D41353438
                IE: Unknown: 010882840B162430486C
                IE: Unknown: 030102
                IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                IE: Unknown: 2D1ABC1917FFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D1602080000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                IE: Unknown: 7F080500000000000040
                IE: Unknown: DD090010180200000C0000
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101840003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: 46057208010000
      Cell 03 - Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
                Channel:3
                Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
                Quality=29/70  Signal level=-81 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"b93ebe"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                          24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=000000020853406a
                Extra: Last beacon: 584ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 0006623933656265
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                IE: Unknown: 030103
                IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                IE: Unknown: 2F0104
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                IE: Unknown: 0B0501000B0000
                IE: Unknown: 2D1ABC191BFFFF000001000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D1603001300000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                IE: Unknown: 7F080500080000000040
                IE: Unknown: DD090010180201000C0000
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101880003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: 46057208010000
      Cell 04 - Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
                Channel:4
                Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
                Quality=22/70  Signal level=-88 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"Jakubowice"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                          11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=000000b940050526
                Extra: Last beacon: 576ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 000A4A616B75626F77696365
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B0C12961824
                IE: Unknown: 030104
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                IE: Unknown: 2D1A2C0000FFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D1604000300000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: DD640050F204104A0001101044000102103B00010310470010325529669ACE1D9E2E3CA1B98B9A8256102100035A544510230006536F66744150102400013010420001301054000800060050F20400011011000241501008000202841049000600372A000120
      Cell 05 - Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
                Channel:5
                Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)
                Quality=21/70  Signal level=-89 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"BEE"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                          9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000001637b936cb
                Extra: Last beacon: 540ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 0003424545
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                IE: Unknown: 030105
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                IE: Unknown: 2D1AEF1103FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000406E6E70D00
                IE: Unknown: 331AEF1103FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000406E6E70D00
                IE: Unknown: 3D1605051300000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 341605051300000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101040003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                IE: Unknown: DD9E0050F204104A0001101044000102103B00010310470010000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F1021000754502D4C494E4B10230009544C2D4D523334323010240003322E3010420003312E301054000800060050F20400011011001E576972656C657373204E2033472F344720526F75746572204D5233343230100800020086103C000101104900140024E26002000101600000020001600100020001
      Cell 06 - Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
                Channel:6
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Quality=24/70  Signal level=-86 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"SuperSiec"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                          24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=000000c7b77a7a04
                Extra: Last beacon: 504ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 0009537570657253696563
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                IE: Unknown: 030106
                IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                IE: Unknown: 2F0104
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                IE: Unknown: 0B050300190000
                IE: Unknown: 2D1ABC191BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D1606080400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                IE: Unknown: 7F080500080000000040
                IE: Unknown: DD090010180203000C0000
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101880003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: 46057208010000
      Cell 07 - Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
                Channel:6
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Quality=35/70  Signal level=-75 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"Sweet_Amber"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                          9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000024d312b45fb
                Extra: Last beacon: 500ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 000B53776565745F416D626572
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                IE: Unknown: 030106
                IE: Unknown: 0706504C20010D14
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                IE: Unknown: 2D1A6E1103FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 331A6E1103FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D1606071500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 341606071500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101830003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                IE: Unknown: DD990050F204104A0001101044000102103B0001031047001000000000000010000000F8D1117395101021000754502D4C494E4B10230009544C2D57523734304E10240003342E3010420003312E301054000800060050F204000110110019576972656C65737320526F7574657220544C2D57523734304E100800020086103C000101104900140024E26002000101600000020001600100020001
      Cell 08 - Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
                Channel:7
                Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
                Quality=24/70  Signal level=-86 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"Salon Shenti"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                          9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=000001101c0a3c2a
                Extra: Last beacon: 476ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 000C53616C6F6E205368656E7469
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                IE: Unknown: 030107
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
      Cell 09 - Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
                Channel:7
                Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
                Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"BML"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                          9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=000000550026e8a5
                Extra: Last beacon: 472ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 0003424D4C
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                IE: Unknown: 030107
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101830003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                IE: Unknown: DD990050F204104A0001101044000102103B00010310470010000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F1021000754502D4C494E4B10230009544C2D57523834314E10240003382E3010420003312E301054000800060050F204000110110019576972656C65737320526F7574657220544C2D57523834314E100800020086103C000101104900140024E26002000101600000020001600100020001
      Cell 10 - Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
                Channel:6
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"obi-kenobi"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                          24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=000000bcef3f8edd
                Extra: Last beacon: 460ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 000A6F62692D6B656E6F6269
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                IE: Unknown: 030106
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                IE: Unknown: 2D1A6E181BFF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D16060F0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: DD090010180200F02C0000
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
      Cell 11 - Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
                Channel:8
                Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
                Quality=20/70  Signal level=-90 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"it hurts when IP"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                          24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=00000065a6bfe8a0
                Extra: Last beacon: 452ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 00106974206875727473207768656E204950
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                IE: Unknown: 030108
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                IE: Unknown: 2D1AEC181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D1608080400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: DD090010180202F02C0000
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
      Cell 12 - Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
                Channel:11
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"ggggg"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                          24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=00000194f89997f8
                Extra: Last beacon: 316ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 00056767676767
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B96A4B0C8EC
                IE: Unknown: 03010B
                IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                IE: Unknown: 2F0104
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 32048C9298E0
                IE: Unknown: 2D1AFC181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D160B081500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: DD090010180205F02C0000
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
      Cell 13 - Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
                Channel:11
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                Quality=22/70  Signal level=-88 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"Socrates"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                          24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=000001ad741051e8
                Extra: Last beacon: 316ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 0008536F637261746573
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                IE: Unknown: 03010B
                IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                IE: Unknown: 2F0104
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: DD7E0050F204104A0001101044000102103B00010310470010138140001DD211B29FFFC67E816B4BFB102100074C696E6B73797310230006526F7574657210240007575254353447321042000C4353563031484335333932321054000800060050F204000110110011576972656C6573732D4720526F75746572100800020088
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180200F4000000

enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

tun0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

br-eaa998a1048e  Interface doesn't support scanning.

docker0   Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

**Ping output for MTU Size and Fragmention**

```
$% ping -s 1472 -c5 google.com
PING google.com (109.173.137.95) 1472(1500) bytes of data.
1480 bytes from cache.google.com (109.173.137.95): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=4.04 ms
1480 bytes from cache.google.com (109.173.137.95): icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=4.15 ms
1480 bytes from cache.google.com (109.173.137.95): icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=3.98 ms
1480 bytes from cache.google.com (109.173.137.95): icmp_seq=4 ttl=58 time=3.74 ms
1480 bytes from cache.google.com (109.173.137.95): icmp_seq=5 ttl=58 time=6.16 ms
```

Comment: Have you tried these steps? http://askubuntu.com/questions/877164/cannot-connect-with-wifi-when-close-to-router/877257#877257

Comment: yes, I have already one most of the thing he has mentioned, I set the country code as well but it's not working. The other problem is it doesn't even show to which wifi it's connected. it just shows it's connected.

Comment: Not working?  Please edit your question to include: `iw reg get` and also: `cat /etc/default/crda`

Comment: I mean the internet speed is very low. and it gets disconnected very often and I have to restart network-manger service to connect again. as I am not able to see wifi networks.

Comment: I thought you meant that the country code wasn't working, but I guess you mean that the wireless entirely isn't working as expected. Yes? Please also add: `sudo iwlist scan` We needn't see the whole thing, just your own network.

Comment: I have just pasted my network, thought that would be enough to identify if it's due to wifi signal, should I paste the whole output

Comment: I'd like to see the whole output. Please redact the MAC address with ****.

Comment: Your network `MTU` could be too high. Install `tracepath` and read `man tracepath` to see how to determine optimal `MTU`. High `MTU` means every packet is fragmented, means twice as many packets, means slowth.

Comment: @waltinator  I don't think MTU sizes is the issue, I don't see any fragmentation or am i looking it wrong. 
I have updated the question with the ping output