# Poor wifi strength from intel wireless-N 7260 on Yoga 2 13? NOT Pro

Tags: wireless, 17.04, intel

Wifi have signal/low power connectivity ie. have to be near router. Was all good historically, then bad in 16.04 and now 17.04 too. Dual booted with Win10. Wifi fine on Win10 and phone etc..

uname -a

```
Linux j-Lenovo-Yoga-2-13 4.10.0-26-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 27 09:30:12 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lspci | grep -i wireless

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
```

dmesg | grep iwl | grep firmware

```
[5.662782] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.459231.0 op_mode iwlmvm
```

sudo lshw -c network

```
  *-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 7260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: wlp1s0
   version: 6b
   serial: e8:2a:ea:5d:2e:3d
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.10.0-26-generic firmware=17.459231.0 ip=192.168.1.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:59 memory:b0400000-b0401fff
```

rfkill list all

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Does it think this is an ideapad cause a problem?
Do I need to backport or start loading firmware and name changing to fool it?? Really?
Cheers

Comment: As a first step you could try to switch off the `bt_coex_active` feature of the `iwlwifi` module. This sometimes causes problems. To do so, `sudo echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`. Then the `iwlwifi` module must be reloaded or just reboot and verify with `cat /sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/bt_coex_active`, which should give a `N`.

Comment: Forgot to mention that you also have to rebuild the initial ramdisk `sudo update-initramfs -k all -u`.

Comment: "start loading firmware and name changing to fool it?? Really?" *No.* I have seen many attempts and no successes. Have you already tried all the steps here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/877164/cannot-connect-with-wifi-when-close-to-router/877257#877257

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I've decided that as when I'm sat away from the router, I can download and upload pretty quickly: it's okay. except the signal icon is only half way on the desktop which is annoying only. Cheers