# How can I install USB Wifi drivers to Lubuntu?

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, lubuntu

I'm trying to bring back an old PC to life. After looking around I concluded that Lubuntu is a great option. It's modern yet fast, using very little resources.

This computer is in a room where it would be very inconvenient to throw a cable to connect to internet, so I have a USB Wifi receiver dongle. It's the ZyXEL G-220 v3 and I have the original driver disc for it, the thing is, it's for Windows.

I am new to Linux and don't really even know where to start. I did find where my devices are located (System Profiler and Benchmark) but still don't know how to make it work.

If anybody could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Here's the lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 058f:9360 Alcor Micro Corp. 8-in-1 Media Card Reader
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0586:3419 ZyXEL Communications Corp. G-220 v3 802.11bg Wireless Adapter [ZyDAS ZD1211B]
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Check if both `wireless-tools` and `wpasupplicant` packages are properly installed on your system.

Comment: Added lsusb to the question and both wireless-tools and wpasupplicant are installed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following from the terminal:

```
sudo -i
modprobe zd1211rw
echo 0586 3419 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/zd1211rw/new_id
exit
```

Did your wireless device come to life? Any clues in the log?

```
dmesg | grep -e zd12 -e wlx
```

If this works, I will edit my answer to add additional steps to make it persistent over reboots.

Comment: The first set of commands brought the device to life. It shows me all the networks around the neighborhood. I choose mine, entered my password and get a spinning wheel on the bottom right where the connections icon is. Then, after a few seconds I get the message "Disconnected - You are now offline / Wireless network". dmesg gives me this: https://justpaste.it/1y8as

Comment: How is your router set up? You might try the tweaks here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/877164/cannot-connect-with-wifi-when-close-to-router/877257#877257

Comment: I tried to follow the steps listed there and I cannot get past the gksu code. I'm missing the program and it says the package might be missing, had been obsoleted or it's only available from another source.

Comment: Please try `sudo nano`

Comment: I added the code REGDOMAIN=US to the crda file, but when I enter sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi I get this message: 'modprobe: FATAL: Module mac80211 is in use.' 'modprobe: FATAL: Error running remove command for iwlwifi.'

Comment: As your driver is *zd1211rw*, you may skip the iwlwifi steps.